# String Formatting VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, string-formatting

I am trying to create a string format that will give me the following output:

```
1-123-345-5671
123-345-5671
```

Basically, if there are only 10 numbers, then don't include the 1-

I know that I can achieve this by checking the length of the string, but I was wondering if there was a way to do it with string formatting, so far I have accomplished this, but if there are 10 number, the dash still gets included

```
String.Format("{0:#-000-000-0000}", CLng(myPhoneNumber))
```

The outcome is:

```
-123-345-5671
```

I am aware that I can apply different formatting depending on the length of the myPhoneNumber, however I was wondering if it is possible to achieve something like this using purely String.Format (so not using if conditions nor replace, etc...)

Comment: You can format the formatting string.  Hard to imagine that this improves the code.  Borken example btw.

Comment: As Hans says, your example outputs and your code sample don't match. Can you clarify if you want three or four digits in the rightmost group?

Comment: Just use the appropriate format based on the number of digits in your number

Comment: What is the type of the input?  Your example uses `CLng(myPhoneNumber)`, but it's not clear what type of variable `myPhoneNumber` is or what kind of values it stores

Comment: I fixed the outputs, the 1 got cut off when I copied it in.

Comment: I've deleted my previous answer that used .Replace, and added a new one using a custom IFormatProvider - please try it out!

Answer (score 1):

I've deleted my previous answer as it could not handle the four digit grouping of your updated question.

However, you can create a custom FormatProvider as follows:

```
Public Class PhoneNumberFormat : Implements IFormatProvider, ICustomFormatter
    Public Function GetFormat(formatType As Type) As Object Implements IFormatProvider.GetFormat
        If formatType Is GetType(ICustomFormatter) Then
            Return Me
        Else
            Return Nothing
        End If
    End Function

    Public Function Format(format1 As String, arg As Object, formatProvider As IFormatProvider) As String Implements ICustomFormatter.Format
        Dim ufmt As String = format1.ToUpper()
        Dim result As String = arg.ToString()

        If ufmt <> "PN" Then Return result
        If result.Length = 10 Then
            Return String.Format("{0:000-000-0000}", arg)
        Else
            Return String.Format("{0:0-000-000-0000}", arg)
        End If
    End Function
End Class
```

Use it like this:

```
String.Format(New PhoneNumberFormat(), "{0:PN}", CLng(myPhoneNumber))
```

The customer formatter looks for the "PN" (PhoneNumber) custom format code, and then formats the argument depending on its length. If the "PN" code is not supplied it just returns the argument with its default ToString().

Please note I have shamelessly lifted this from the IFormatProvider documentation here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.iformatprovider(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-3

Still I've given myself a nice little intro in to how to create these, something I've never done before :)

Answer (score 0):

Get the number of digits in your number and use the proper format based on that.

```
Module Module1
    Sub Main()
        Dim phoneNumber As Long = 1234567891
        Dim numberOfDigits As Integer = Math.Log10(phoneNumber) + 1
        Console.WriteLine(String.Format(If(numberOfDigits = 11, "{0:0-000-000-0000}", "{0:000-000-0000}"), phoneNumber))
        Console.ReadLine()
    End Sub
End Module
```

Results:

```
123-456-7891
```

If phoneNumber is 12345678911

Results:

```
1-234-567-8911
```